Does it matter if nameservers are uppercase?
I'm currently migrating a bunch of websites to a new server and I don't have access to some of the website domains in order to update the DNS, however their nameservers are pointing to a domain I control e.g. ns1.server1.com
So after a bulk migrate session I updated ns1.server1.com from an A record that was pointing directly to the IP of the old server, to a CNAME record that points to ns1.server2.com, where ns1.server2.com is an A record that points to the IP of the new server.
All sites sporting ns1.server1.com seem to be fine after the update, however one site's DNS is totally down and the only difference is that when I do a whois to check the nameservers, the nameservers are in all caps (e.g. NS1.SERVER1.COM) and the sites that are working are all lower case (ns1.server1.com).
I'm not sure why the DNS is failing for this one particular domain and that is the only difference I can find.

Does it matter if nameservers are uppercase? No.

no it doesn't. go on ns1.server1.com and check this
dig @localhost <site_that_is_not_working> make sure it's returning correct ip
do the same from an outside client dig at-ns1.server.com  it should return updated ip address
